# Download excel file with .NET Core 3 and React

Tags: c#, excel, reactjs

I'm trying to download an excel file
In my controller I'm doing this:

```
[HttpGet("downloadExcel")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadExcel()
{

var excel = new DownloadExcel();
var fileMemoryStream = excel.GenerateExcel(await students.GetStudentsExcelDownload());

return File(
    fileMemoryStream,
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    String.Concat("Students Excel.xlsx"));
}
```

And in my TypeScript service I'm doing this:

```
public async downloadExcel(): Promise<any> {
    const response = await this._httpClient.get<any>(`${this.downloadExcel}`);
    console.log("RESPONSE", response)
    return response;
}
```

But when I cosole.log the responde is like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G87BP.png]

How can I download the file excel?

Comment: What are you expecting an Excel file to log to the console?  This looks like it may indeed be successfully downloading the file.  But then what do you plan to do with that file?

Comment: I want to download that file, but I can't figure how can I work with that data in the response to achieve that

Comment: I'm hesitant to vote as an exact duplicate (since the one I found is specific to jQuery), but this question has useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax  The approach in the top answer is to dynamically create a hidden `<a>` element which references the downloaded data and invoke a click on that element.  The effect is that the browser should handle the download natively.  You might even forgo that and just direct the user to the URL instead of using AJAX, to let the browser handle the file response natively.

Comment: @David Thank you!